# debian wheeze nginx compile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, debian, passenger, rvm

I am using rvm in debian wheeze, i want to run rails with passenger, and i get error on nginx standalone core compile. I am using ruby 1.9.2 and i have install in my system the proper libs.

```
src/core/ngx_resolver.c: In function ‘ngx_resolver_process_ptr’:
src/core/ngx_resolver.c:1425:43: error: variable ‘qclass’ set but not used [-    Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
src/core/ngx_resolver.c:1425:36: error: variable ‘qtype’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make[1]: *** [objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/miza-passenger-standalone-1133/nginx-1.0.0'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```